# Universal Control top/bottom instead of left/right

Tags: macos

When I use Universal Control, I can swipe to the right or left side of my screen, and it moves the cursor to my iPad. Is there a way to do the same thing with the top/bottom of my screen?

Right now my iPad is below my desktop monitor, so it would make more sense if the mouse moved between the screens via top/bottom edges rather than left/right.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to initially set it up via the right/left, then go to System > Displays and rearrange the screen so it's top/bottom.

I don't think there's a way to do this without the extra step, since [according to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212757), this is expected behavior:

> Use your mouse or trackpad to move the cursor past the left or right edge of your screen in the general direction of the iPad or other Mac, **even if the other device is positioned below your screen.** You can [arrange your displays](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212757#arrange) more precisely later.